# Dynamic path to spl_autoload

Tags: php

Currently I'm recursively looking through my classes folder in order to find the path to my class in order to include it. The problem is, I have many different classes in various different folders that I would like to include. The code that I've created is messy but it works.

The code below is not the recursive function that I've created but it will work for a defined path within the myAutoloader() function.

**Is there any way to pass a path to spl_autoload function in PHP?**

```
    spl_autoload_register('myAutoloader');

    function myAutoloader($className) {
        $path = '/classes';

        include $path . $className . '.php';
    }

    //-------------------------------------

    // this one will work, as its path is specified in spl_autoload
    $myClass1 = new MyClass1(); 

    //this is located in /classes/other so it wont work
    $myClass2 = new MyClass2();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to pass the path to the callback function specified in `spl_autoload_register`.
You can only create this awareness inside the function:

```
function myAutoloader($className) {

    $paths = array(
    'Class1' => '/subpath',
    'Class2' => '/subpath/extra',
    );

    include $paths[$className] . '/'. $className . '.php';
}
```

That said, I **strongly discourage you** folliwing this approach. Instead I really suggest you to:

- Let `composer` create your autoload insted doing this manually.
- Invest 10 minutes reading [PSR-4 Specifications](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

Answer (score 1):

If your class "MyClass1" is stored with filename like "MyClass1.php" you can do:

```
set_include_path('/classes:/classes/other');
spl_autoload_register();
```